# How copying a unique_ptr of one type to another works

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

With reference to the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::make_unique;

struct Base {};
struct Derived : public Base {};

int main() {

    auto base_uptr = std::unique_ptr<Base>{make_unique<Derived>()};
    return 0;
}
```

which constructor gets called for the `unique_ptr`?  I took a look at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) and the constructors I found (pre c++17) were (for the sake of completion)

```
constexpr unique_ptr();
constexpr unique_ptr( nullptr_t );
explicit unique_ptr( pointer p );
unique_ptr( pointer p, /* see below */ d1 );
unique_ptr( pointer p, /* see below */ d2 );
unique_ptr( unique_ptr&& u );

template< class U, class E >
unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u );
```

None of them seem to accept the pointer of the other type.  What am I missing?  Which constructor gets called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Number 6, the template constructor.

```
template< class U, class E >
unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u );
```

Which requires, among a few other conditions, that *"`unique_ptr<U, E>::pointer` is implicitly convertible to `pointer`"*. In other words, `U*` needs to be implicitly convertible to the pointer type which your `unique_ptr` stores. Which in your case, it is, since `Derived*` is implicitly convertible to `Base*`.